Load pre trained LSTM model in R
I've trained an LSTM model in Python but now I want to test it in R to compare the execution time.
To avoid retraining I saved the trained LSTM in Python as following.
from keras.models import model_from_json

# Define the file paths for the saved model architecture and weights
architecture_path = '59acc_acf_pacf.json'
weights_path = '59acc_acf_pacf.weights.h5'

# Load the model architecture from JSON
with open(architecture_path, 'r') as json_file:
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()

# Reconstruct the model from the architecture
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

# Load the model weights into the reconstructed model
model.load_weights(weights_path)

print("Model architecture and weights loaded successfully.")

Now, how can I load it and then test it in R?

Maybe start with a simple google search?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Plagon Have you read the link you attached? Does not explain how to load .json and then use it.

Hi @GANZA ,You want to load and test your model in R. With the help of the Keras package, you can load models from JSON. First, you need to import and load libraries ;after that load the model and weight.Also create the Test data including normalization and reshaping. Test it with your data to compare the execution time with Python.
